# How to get inserted document's id in transaction? (arangoDB)

Tags: php, transactions, arangodb

I've been searching the web a lot for clues but can't seem to find any...

```
public function createNew($name, $type, $restriction,$picture){
   global $connection;
   $trans=new Transaction($connection,array( 'collections' => array( 'write' => array( 'group_relations','groups' ),'read'=> array( 'group_relations','groups' ) ), 'waitForSync' => true ));
   $trans->setAction('function(){
      var db= require("@arangodb").db;
      var arr=db.groups.insert({"name":"'.$name.'","type":"'.$type.'","restriction":"'.$restriction.'","picture":"'.$picture.'"}).toArray();
                db.group_relations.insert({"_from":"users/'.$_SESSION['uid'].'","_to":"groups/"+arr[0]["_id"],"status":"admin"});
      }');
   $trans->execute();
}
```

this is a PHP function that makes a transaction. In the transaction, I'm trying to create a group, get its id and insert it in the relation collection between the creator and the new group.

Basically make the creator of the group the admin.

> "**Fatal error**:  Uncaught triagens\ArangoDb\ServerException: 17 db.groups.insert(...).toArray is not a function".

Any solutions?

Comment: `toArray` is not a function in `arangodb`. You might want to [`cast`](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/AQL/Functions/TypeCast.html) the JSON to an array. ~> `TO_ARRAY({foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: [3, 4, 5]})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `insert({...})` is always an object. The result of `insert([{...},{...},...,{...}])` is always an array. In either case `.toArray()` does not help.

So if you'd like to make sure, that you have an array as a result type, please use the array `insert` also for single entries:

```
var arr=db.groups.insert(
  [{"name":"'.$name.'",
    "type":"'.$type.'",
    "restriction":"'.$restriction.'",
    "picture":"'.$picture.'"}]);
```

So in order to get back the ids from your inserts only:

```
var ids = []; 
db.groups.insert([{...},...,{...}]).forEach(
  function(obj) {ids.push(obj._id)});
...
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but i still get:Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught triagens\ArangoDb\ServerException: 1233 edge attribute missing or invalid
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\ShareOn\arangodb\lib\triagens\ArangoDb\Connection.php</b> on line <b>522</b><br />

Comment: Would you please share your line 522 with us, please?

Comment: actually, I fixed it. I had to add " to [0] it should be ["0"] for some weird reason despite being an integer